# How can I print an object?

Tags: swift

I want to print an object in the console in Swift.

In Java I would override the `public String toString()` method.

How can I do that in Swift?

```
class MyClass {
    var i : Int
    var j : Int
// ...
//  method to return a String {
        return String(i) + ", " + String(j)
    }
}

var mc = MyClass(5, 10)
print(mc) // 5, 10
```

Comment: That's not even valid Swift code

Comment: Your code isn't valid. I added a class implementation so it'll compile. If you want to avoid retain cycles, you may consider using a struct instead of a class and you can get rid of the initializer.

Comment: Of course it is a fragment only

Answer (score 1):

You need your entity to conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and implement var `description`.

```swift
class MyClass: CustomStringConvertible {
    var i : Int // Integer doesn't exist in swift
    var j : Int

    var description: String {
        String(i) + ", " + String(j) // return is implicit
    }
}
```

In general, Swift classes don't inherit from any super class, so they don't have basic methods like `toString`, `equal` and so on.

Every implementation needs to conform to a specific `protocol` (a java `interface`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to conform to the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol. Then you implement the `description` property.

```swift
class MyClass: CustromStringConvertible {
    var i: Int
    var j: Int

    // ...

    var description: String {
        return "\(i), \(j)"
    }
}

var mc = MyClass(5, 10)
print(mc) // 5, 10
```

From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible):

> Types that conform to the CustomStringConvertible protocol can provide their own representation to be used when converting an instance to a string. The String(describing:) initializer is the preferred way to convert an instance of any type to a string. If the passed instance conforms to CustomStringConvertible, the String(describing:) initializer and the print(_:) function use the instance’s custom description property.
>
> Accessing a type’s description property directly or using CustomStringConvertible as a generic constraint is discouraged.

For debugging purposes, you might want to conform to `CustomDebugStringConvertible` and implement `debugDescription` instead ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customdebugstringconvertible)).

This would look like this (Playground file):

```swift
import Foundation

struct Point {
    let x: Int, y: Int
}

extension Point: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "NON-DEBUG - (\(x), \(y))"
    }
}

extension Point: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var debugDescription: String {
        return "DEBUG - (\(x), \(y))"
    }
}

let p = Point(x: 21, y: 30)

print(p)
// NON-DEBUG - (21, 30)

print(String(reflecting: p))
// DEBUG - (21, 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `CustomStringConvertible` or `CustomDebugStringConvertible`:

```swift
class MyClass {
    var i: Int
    var j: Int
    
    init(i: Int, j: Int) {
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
    }
}

extension MyClass: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        "\(i), \(j)"
    }
}

extension MyClass: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var debugDescription: String {
        "\(i), \(j)"
    }
}
```

As a suggestion, if you're just going to be passing this around and don't need to hang onto it, you could change it to a value type like a `struct` and you'd get an initializer for free.

I'd recommend extending classes to utilize protocols like `CustomStringConvertible` and `CustomDebugStringConvertible` to keep your code neat.